# Access Component Object in External Callback?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

In the following code, in which `submit` is a method in an external JavaScript module, is it possible for `submit()` to access the component object?

**Component.html**

```
<button on:click={submit}>Submit</button>

<script>
    import { submit } from './';
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
export function submit()
{
    console.log(this); // <button>Submit</button>
};
```

Before Svelte 3, `this` would be the component object, but in Svelte 3, `this` seems to be the  target element.

Comment: There is no 'component object' inside the instance any more — can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey. I'm considering migrating from Svelte 2 to 3. I prefer to have JavaScript in its own files, rather than the component file. Thus, in Svelte 2, I had no substantial code in a component `<script>`. Instead, functions were imported from an external JavaScript file, and passed in the behaviours object. If I wanted to do something when a button was clicked, I would pass an external function in the `methods` of the behaviours object. It would be called with `this` being the component object, allowing properties to be read and wrote, and events to be fired. I'm trying to achieve this.

Comment: That style isn't really possible in Svelte 3 — you would have to pass around callbacks that interact with your local state, or use [stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. May I ask why? I'm unfamiliar with the underlying Svelte 3 implementation. I was hopeful because there seems to be a minimal API with `$set()`, `$on()`, and `$destroy()`. I'm curious whether that could be exposed to methods like in my example, and whether there could be any scope for `$get()`, $`fire()`, and such. Similarly, I was unable to locate an equivalent in Svelte 3 to the `state` event in Svelte 2. Could this external JavaScript style be supported in future? I love Svelte for its template language and minimalism, but value separating HTML and JavaScript.