# Accessing Svelte component properties in a callback?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

Imagine that you have a lot of properties in a component:

```js
let a = 'foo';
let b = 'bar';
// ...
let z = 'baz';
```

You then want to do something like update all of them from an external callback, like in another library (i.e. something that isn't and can't be a Svelte component itself).

A simple use case is just an AJAX method to load in a bunch of data (assume this ajax function works and you can pass it a callback):

```js
onMount(async function() {
  ajax('/data', function(data) {
    a = data.a;
    b = data.b;
    // ...
    z = data.z;
  });
});
```

This works, but it's incredibly boilerplaty. What I'd really like is a way to loop through all the properties so they can be assigned to programmatically, especially without prior knowledge on the outside library/callback's part.

Is there no way to get access to a Svelte component and its properties so you can loop through them and assign them from an outside function?

Vue has a simple solution to this, because you can pass the component around, and still check and assign to its properties:

```js
var vm = this;
ajax('/data', function(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    if (vm.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      vm[key] = data[key];
    }
  });
});
```

I have seen some solutions to this, but they're all outdated - none of them work with Svelte 3.

Apologies if this has been asked before. I've spent days trying to figure this out to avoid all that extra boilerplate and the closest I could find is [Access Component Object in External Callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571882/access-component-object-in-external-callback) which does not have an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you could put the ajax call in the parent component and have the data returned from it stored in a temporary object, that you then pass on to the component using the spread operator.

```
<Component { ...dataObject }></Component>

let dataObject = {};
onMount(async function() {
  ajax('/data', function(data) {
    dataObject = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: This solution is clean and easy, but there cases when you don't like polluting parent scope - but still, JS spread operator is extremely useful.

Comment: I had to re-work my app a little bit to make this work, but it is a nice solution in the end, and putting shared code in the parent component makes sense to me. I don't think it applies everywhere, as @RafałWarzycha mentioned, but in those other cases the other answer on this page is a good fit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the boilerplate by using destructuring:

```js
onMount(async function() {
  ajax('/data', data => {
    ({ a, b, ..., z } = data);
  });
});
```

But if you have a very large number of variables, you might be better off just putting them in an object in the first place:

```js
let stuff;

onMount(async function() {
  ajax('/data', data => {
    stuff = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Putting everything into an object is a good idea for simplifying in some cases, and I will definitely be using that. Thank you!

Not being able to check whether or not a property exists within a component seems like a pretty serious limitation on svelte's part though.